# ARM get EventHub Namespace shareAcessPolicyKey

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

My goal is to deploy a streaming analytics who contain an eventhub as input. To do this, I need to get the *shareAcessPolicyKey*. After some search, I found the *ListKeys* function but still not working for my case.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "The Resource 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/tbiNamespace' under resource group 'devOps' was not found."
  }
```

.

**EDIT - Solution** 
`"sharedAccessPolicyKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/authorizationRules',parameters('namespaces'), parameters('AuthorizationRules_name')),'2017-04-01').primaryKey]"`

---

Create the namespaces rules

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/AuthorizationRules",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('namespaces_tornosbi_name'), '/', parameters('AuthorizationRules_RootManageSharedAccessKey_name'))]",
    "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
    "location": "North Europe",
    "scale": null,
    "properties": {
        "rights": [
            "Listen",
            "Manage",
            "Send"
        ]
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces', parameters('namespaces_tornosbi_name'))]"
    ]
},
```

create the resource streaming jobs input

```
"resources": [{
                "type": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/inputs",
                "name": "[concat(parameters('streamingjobs_tornosbi_name'), '/', parameters('inputs_eh_input_name'))]",
                "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
                "scale": null,
                "properties": {
                    "type": "Stream",
                    "datasource": {
                        "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/EventHub",
                        "properties": {
                            "eventHubName": "[parameters('eventhubs_tornosbi_hub_name')]",
                            "serviceBusNamespace": "[parameters('namespaces_tornosbi_name')]",
                            "sharedAccessPolicyName": "[parameters('AuthorizationRules_RootManageSharedAccessKey_name')]",
                    "sharedAccessPolicyKey": "[listKeys(resourceId(concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/','eventhub','/authorizationRules'),parameters('namespaces_tornosbi_name'),parameters('eventhubs_tornosbi_hub_name'),parameters('AuthorizationRules_RootManageSharedAccessKey_name')),'2016-03-01').primaryKey]"

                        }
                    },
                    "compression": {
                        "type": "None"
                    },
                    "serialization": {
                        "type": "Json",
                        "properties": {
                            "encoding": "UTF8"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs', parameters('streamingjobs_tornosbi_name'))]",
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces', parameters('namespaces_tornosbi_name'))]",
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs', parameters('namespaces_tornosbi_name'), parameters('eventhubs_tornosbi_hub_name'))]"
                ]
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error clearly states there is no such resource in the resource group. Impossible to help you without knowing where the resource is, but `resourceId()` function accepts resource group and subscription as arguments:

```
resourceId(subscription, resourcegroup, 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/eventhub/authorizationRules',
    namespace, eventhub, rule)
```

ps. you dont need to do `concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/','eventhub','/authorizationRules'),` just use a string

Comment: I tried to put the subscription and the resourcegroup ```"sharedAccessPolicyKey": "[listKeys(resourceId(subscription().id, resourceGroup().id,'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/eventhub/authorizationRules',parameters('namespaces_tornosbi_name'),parameters('eventhubs_tornosbi_hub_name'),parameters('AuthorizationRules_RootManageSharedAccessKey_name')),'2016-03-01').primaryKey]"``` But I can't deploy I receive the error message function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument which must be resource type including resource provider namespace. If you want I can put all my template !

Comment: there is no point in putting `resourceGroup().id` (should be name btw) if the resource is in the same resource group (because same RG is implied). and if its in the other resource group it makes no sense to use it, because it would provide wrong input

Comment: All resources are in the same RG in my case. My template create many resources like eventhub, adls, adla, etc... When I deploy I need to create a new RG and all resources will be create in. Check out my edit post.

Comment: what happens if you rerun the template? this might be due to the resource not available when you run it for the first time?

Comment: still deploy failed. It's still not found the ressource... So strange... Do I need in two template ? I mean the first template create all ressource and I after I run a template who create the input and ouptut for my streamjobs

Comment: okay, are you sure that such a resource exists in the resource group? name should match

Comment: Look my new **edit** I found something strange... If I remove my streamjobsinput resource all work perfectly ! But if I run with it the resource Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/AuthorizationRules failed

Comment: ok, sorry I'm a bit busy right now, i'll look into your template later.

Comment: No worry and thank you for your attention and time spend to my problem !

Comment: God... I target the wrong resource like you said... ShareAccessKey was on the eventhub namespsace ->  ```"sharedAccessPolicyKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/authorizationRules',parameters('namespaces_tornosbi_name'), parameters('AuthorizationRules_RootManageSharedAccessKey_name')),'2017-04-01').primaryKey]"```

Comment: old post i know... but i've been trying to extract the api date from the provider like so.. `providers('Microsoft.EventHub', 'namespaces').apiVersions[0])` failing miserably though... reverted to just using the date 

Comment: microsoft discourages that @m1nkeh

Comment: Really? Where do they discourage this?

Comment: i saw it somewhere, but even if you think about this - it doesnt make sense. there is no point in using latest api version (unless you want to run into unexpected behaviors) @m1nkeh

Comment: makes sense, i have taken it out of all my scripts 